# How to pass a Future instead of a value as parameter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Suppose I need to create this **Widget()**:

```
TextButton(
   onPressed: () {},
   child: const Text( myModel.getNameOfCustomer() ),
)
```

Currently, my app queries a **EModel** class to obtain the value of nameOfCustomer in a synchronic fashion.  This is due to the fact, that **EModel** maintains its storage fully locally.

Suppose, I want to change **EModel** in such a way, that the class itself queries e.g. a database. Then, **getNameOfCustomer()** needs to return it data asynchronously and this wrapped inside a Future.

**Q: How may I pass the **Future<>** as the string parameter for `Text()`?**

Does `Text()` has a parameter to pass `Future<> futureData` instead of `String data` and thus would itself eventually read the value of `futureData` and set its `String data`?

**In other words...**

If my app works synchronously regarding the UI and I switch to an asynchronous data model, do I need to rewrite the whole application?

Does a standard pattern exist, which prepares for such a migration?

Comment: Check out the [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).
Wrap your Text widget with this, and you'll be able to wait for that Future, and furthermore, while waiting, you can display something else, like a loading indicator/skeleton.

Comment: OK, sounds good. May I use it even in cases, in case my EModel provides data async bit immediately due to internal storage? Does in this case a request of snapshot.hasData skips the no data widget and immediately shows the data available widget?

Comment: Should I always use FutureBuilder just in case I later switch? Does this is a best practice?

Comment: I don't think it counts as a best practice, to my personal oppinion it is quite easy to switch later. Yes, if the data fetching is done in milliseconds, it will skip to displaying the data :)